# Code or Tools to Export FoxPro to dBase

Tags: c#, foxpro, dbase

I want to convert FoxPro table into dBase IV table. Can someone help me?

That could be a code snippet or a third party tool that works with c#

Prasanna

Comment: In my experience, most software can't tell the difference betweenn the two.  For example, the POS software in use in our company expects dBase files, but reads FoxPro files just as if they were dBase files.  Is there a reason you need to do this?

Comment: Why do you want to convert obsolete format A into obsolete format B for use with modern language C (#)? If conversion is going to break legacy compatibility, why not go to a currently supported database format (SQL Server, MySQL, CouchDB, etc.)?

Comment: David/TrueWill

The reason I want this conversion is I am doing some modifications to a dBase file associated with Shapefile. I used vfpoledb.1 provider to do those changes. With those changes I create a new .dbf file as it is easier and faster to do. This new file is not recognized by the application. I presume this is because what vfpoledb creates is a foxpro file.

Prasanna

Comment: David/TrueWill  Shapefile is a file used in Geographic InformationSystems. However there is a .dbf file associated with the shapefile(.shp) that carries the attributes of the objects in the shapfile.

Comment: @David and TrueWill, please read the xbase specification. The version of FoxPro may impact the file structure.  This then eliminated the "DBase compatibility" aspect of foxpro.

Answer (score 1):

Are you familiar with 
[wikipedias article on xbase?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBase)

What about the [dbf file structure specification?](http://www.clicketyclick.dk/databases/xbase/format/dbf.html#DBF_STRUCT)

FoxPro and DBase are variants of XBase.  However as you read the spec you'll see there are some important differences.

I've never had a need to convert between the two. If faced with the need, I would either use [codebase](http://www.codebase.com/) or [xbase](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xdb/).  I've used codebase in C++ once in the past. It was fast, effective, easy to use, and fairly stable.  I've never used xbase.  Despite being commercial codebase comes with sourcecode -- handy if you need to fix a bug in the library, or do some other customizations.  xBase, being open source, I would assume, has similar flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

DBase and FoxPro tables are very similar. But to convert a FoxPro table to DBase, try this from the VFP command window:

USE someFoxproTable
COPY TO someOtherTableName TYPE FOXPLUS
CLOSE ALL